# gosn serialize two objects separately

Tags: javascript, gson

I have objects of Date and Timestamp in a class.
I want to serialize Timestamp as YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss and let Date serialize as YYYY-MM-dd

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(experimentItems);
```

This code will get me two YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss formats.

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonAdapter Annotation!

```
class Person {
    @JsonAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
    private Date birthday;
    @JsonAdapter(TimestampAdapter.class)
    private TimeStamp birthdayAndTime;
}
```